# Django lockdown authentication - Login form not working

Tags: django

I've been investigating methods of locking down an entire page. A colleague drew my attention to [django-lockdown](https://bitbucket.org/carljm/django-lockdown/src). I've installed and and my code looks like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS += ('lockdown',)
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES += ('lockdown.middleware.LockdownMiddleware',)
LOCKDOWN_PASSWORD = 'letmein'
```

I'm using the supplied template code that comes with bit bucket that looks like this:

```
{% extends "lockdown/base.html" %}

{% block title %}Coming soon...{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div id="lockdown">
  <h2>Coming soon...</h2>

  <p>This is not yet available to the public.</p>

  {% if form %}

  <form action="" method="post">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Preview"></p>
  </form>

  {% endif %}

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

When I run a server locally I get no errors however the form itself does not appear on the screen. There is no place to type in a password which leads me to believe {% if form %} probably isn't true.

There isn't a lot of documentation available online so I'm struggling to fix this error.

Comment: could you show your view code?

Comment: @HieuNguyen http://pastebin.com/yTxTUnNY

Comment: I assume putting the password in a tuple fix the issue for you, correct?  I'm seeing a [similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711085/django-lockdown-password-prompt-not-displayed), except that I have the password in a tuple.

Comment: @user2233706 I had something similar to that.  Putting the password in a tuple as below fixed it. I can't quite recall how I fixed it. You're using the default forms? If I recall correctly there's an `{{% if %}}` statement in the form template. If you try taking that out it will display. I just made a custom form. I've upvoted your question in the hope someone can answer it.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I'm using the default form.  The problem is that this only happens on the development server, and the packages are installed automatically with `pip` outside my source tree.  I can include lockdown with my source tree, but I would prefer not to do that.

Comment: Yes, the problem is because of the password.  I've answered my own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your lockdown password should be [a tuple](https://bitbucket.org/carljm/django-lockdown/overview#rst-header-lockdown-passwords). Something like LOCKDOWN_PASSWORDS = ('letmein', 'beta').

Also you should not be writing a template to get it working. Django-lockdown is batteries included. Just out of the box (this and only this):

- pip install django-lockdown,
- add 'lockdown', (with trailing comma) to APPS,
- add 'lockdown.middleware.LockdownMiddleware', (with trailing comma) to the middleware,
- add LOCKDOWN_PASSWORDS = ('letmein', 'beta')

[all these things in settings]

Comment: I had LOCKDOWN_PASSWORD= ('password'), which I found elsewhere. That did not work because I was not using the tuple, and the variable name was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from documentation:

> To enable admin preview of locked-down sites or views with passwords, set the LOCKDOWN_PASSWORDS setting to a tuple of one or more plain-text passwords.

So you should have this in setting:

```
LOCKDOWN_PASSWORDS = ('let me in', )
```

Comment: This is just copying my answer.

Comment: Sorry I type in the answer at the same time, which happens quite often in SO