# django-lockdown password prompt not displayed

Tags: django

I'm having the same problem as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919234/django-lockdown-authentication-login-form-not-working).  However, on my local machine, the password prompt is displayed, but when I push to my development server on Openshift, the password prompt is not displayed.  Instead, only this is displayed:

> Coming soon...
>
> This is not yet available to the public.

Again, as the linked question states, it seems like the `form` context variable is not passed to the template.  I have not changed anything in lockdown.  Furthermore, this used to work.  I've gone through the history of my `settings.py` and no smoking gun.  What's irritating is that this works on my local machine.  Here's the lockdown related variables in my `settings.py`:

```
USE_LOCKDOWN = True

if USE_LOCKDOWN:
  INSTALLED_APPS += ('lockdown',)
  MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES += ('lockdown.middleware.LockdownMiddleware',)
  LOCKDOWN_PASSWORD = ('mypassword')
  LOCKDOWN_URL_EXCEPTIONS = (r'^/admin',)
  LOCKDOWN_FORM = 'lockdown.forms.LockdownForm'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem.

When I had initially installed lockdown using pip on my local machine, pypi only had version 0.1.1, which uses `LOCKDOWN_PASSWORD`.  In my settings.py, I used a string for the password, not a tuple.  In the question I had linked to in my original post, the answers mentioned passing a tuple instead of string.  I tried that, and that did not work.

When you push code onto OpenShift and don't specify the version in `setup.py`, it downloads the latest version of the package.  In the latest version of lockdown, `LOCKDOWN_PASSWORDS` is used instead and that expects a tuple.  I updated my `settings.py` file accordingly, and now a password prompt is displayed.